# .htaccess for MODx Evo site behind Cloudflare with https

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare

Looks like a bit easy question but I can't done that right, so I'd ask you for a little help:

I have some small site made on MODx Evo. It is placed behind CloudFlare (free tariff, very basic features used), mainly for their free https. Now I try to set only one address as a base one:

- http://example.org
- https://example.org <-- this one should be base
- http://www.example.org
- https://www.example.org

I do use default MODx Evo .htaccess to provide nice URLs and some basic PHP settings, which looks like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets|js|css|images|img)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here is everything but the part which does the redirect from www to non-www domain, and it is stock settings.

Now I need to do another two redirect conditions:

1. http -> https
2. www -> non-www

This is where I'm stuck. I can easily redirect non-www to www, but as I add http/https part, I'm getting 301 loop.

The site itself is on Apache (the Cloudflare adds their special Nginx version).

Please advice what should I add to the **.htaccess** shown above to have **all** 3 domain variants shown above redirected nicely to **https://example.org** one?

Answer (score 0):

To my great surprise, this was possible to do with Page Rules on Cloudflare itself, which is the best solution as for me, since no backend (like my server behind the Cloudflare) involved.

Thanks Cloudflare!

Answer (score 0):

.httacces may not work

I founded solution by edit config (https://gitlab.com/snippets/1906338)

To fix https thro cloudflare needs edit var `$secured` like this in manager/includes/config.inc.php - add checking cloudflare `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"]`

```
$secured = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') || 
(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"]) && $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"] == '{"scheme":"https"}');
```